# Browser support for certain if statements

Tags: javascript

I was wondering what browsers (that are within jquery's support range) support this kind of if statements:

`var a = true;
    if(a) {
     alert('a')
    }`

Comment: *Even* IE, yes I know it's hard to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All browsers that support JavaScript 1.3 which is when the `===` operator was introduced.

`(a === true)` evaluates to `true` given that a is true.

And because `true` is exactly the same as `true` the behaviour is exactly the same.

So examples of browsers that don't support JavaScript are can be seen of this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#JavaScript_support

Comment: I'm not sure if they meant it the way around they did it, but the second wasn't supported until 1.3

Answer (score 2):

No.

For example Mosaic and lynx, even the most recent versions, fail on those tests. Netscape Navigator too was totally unable to get this right before version 2.

Comment: Bleh, knew I should have clarified. I meant IE 6+, Safari 3+, Latest crome and FF2+ -.-

Answer (score 1):

The first supported by all javascript browsers from NN2 (the first javascript browser).

`===` was introduced with javascript 1.3, (ECMA-262 first edition) used in NN4.06 and IE4.

Opera and Safari supported both from their first javascript implementations; 7.0 and 3.0-5 respectively.

Firefox, Chrome and Chromium all post-date that.

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different things:

```
var a = true; if(a) { alert('a') }
```

Check whether the value of `a` "evaluates" to true. A.k.a. it is true-ish.

```
var a = true; if(a === true) { alert('a') }
```

This also checks the type. So it check whether `a` contains the boolean value `true`.

However they both are supported across fairly modern user agents (most text browsers wont support it though).